# Observer pattern in Go language

Tags: go, observer-pattern

This problem is pretty common: an object should notify all its subscribers when some event occurs. In C++ we may use `boost::signals` or something else. But how to do this in Go language? It would be nice to see some working code example where a couple of objects are subscribed to a publisher and process notifications.

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple in Go. Use channels. This is the kind of thing they're made for.

```
type Publish struct {
    listeners []chan *Msg
}

type Subscriber struct {
    Channel chan *Msg
}

func (p *Publisher) Sub(c chan *Msg) {
    p.appendListener(c)
}

func (p *Publisher) Pub(m *Msg) {
    for _, c := range p.listeners {
        c <- Msg
    }
}

func (s *Subscriber) ListenOnChannel() {
    for {
        data := <-s.Channel
        //Process data
    }
}

func main() {
    for _, v := range subscribers {
        p.Sub(v.Channel)
        go v.ListenOnChannel()
    }
    //Some kind of wait here
}
```

Obviously this isn't exactly a working code sample. But it's close.

Comment: Be careful with blocking channel operations.

Comment: @MizardX of course, normally I'd have control chan's as well, like chan bool and use select {}, and quit on a recv from the control channel. But that's all fairly trivial and a bit excessive for a basic example.

Comment: @MizardX: isn't that a bit like saying "be careful with pointer arithmetic" in C? Being careful with channels is 90% of Go programming ;-)

Comment: This is technically sending a pointer to the same message to all subscribers, which is easier on memory but potentially dangerous (mutable event). If the channel was not of type *Msg, but "chan Msg", would I then be sending copies of the same message all around? Asuming small messages, that would seem like a safer solution.

Comment: What is `Publisher` and how is access to it synchronized? It's not trivial to implement and I'm sure that is the *real* question here.

Answer (score 2):

Here I give a classific implementation without channels, be free to refer this [post](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/observer-design-pattern-in-golang-with-an-example-6c24898059b1)
[image]

Assumed Example:
Suppose you are interested in the stock market. You have the following needs: You want to keep track of the stock prices of a particular company (e.g. Apple Inc). You would not like to miss any stock price update especially if the price is dropping to a certain point. You would like to be notified of all the stock price updates.

interfaces:

```
// Subject interface
type Subject interface {
    Attach(o Observer) (bool, error)
    Detach(o Observer) (bool, error)
    Notify() (bool, error)
}

// Observer Interface
type Observer interface {
    Update(string)
}
```

Concrete Observer object

```
// Concrete Observer: StockObserver
type StockObserver struct {
    name string
}

func (s *StockObserver) Update(t string) {
    // do something
    println("StockObserver:", s.name, "has been updated,", "received subject string:", t)
}
```

Concrete Subject object

```
// Concrete Subject: stockMonitor
type StockMonitor struct {
    // internal state
    ticker string
    price  float64

    observers []Observer
}

func (s *StockMonitor) Attach(o Observer) (bool, error) {

    for _, observer := range s.observers {
        if observer == o {
            return false, errors.New("Observer already exists")
        }
    }
    s.observers = append(s.observers, o)
    return true, nil
}

func (s *StockMonitor) Detach(o Observer) (bool, error) {

    for i, observer := range s.observers {
        if observer == o {
            s.observers = append(s.observers[:i], s.observers[i+1:]...)
            return true, nil
        }
    }
    return false, errors.New("Observer not found")
}

func (s *StockMonitor) Notify() (bool, error) {
    for _, observer := range s.observers {
        observer.Update(s.String())
    }
    return true, nil
}

func (s *StockMonitor) SetPrice(price float64) {
    s.price = price
    s.Notify()
}

func (s *StockMonitor) String() string {
    convertFloatToString := strconv.FormatFloat(s.price, 'f', 2, 64)
    return "StockMonitor: " + s.ticker + " $" + convertFloatToString
}
```

main.go

```
func main() {

    // Create a new stockMonitor object
    stockMonitor := &StockMonitor{
        ticker: "AAPL",
        price:  0.0,
    }

    observerA := &StockObserver{
        name: "Observer A",
    }
    observerB := &StockObserver{
        name: "Observer B",
    }

    // Attach our Observers to the stockMonitor
    stockMonitor.Attach(observerA)
    stockMonitor.Attach(observerB)

    // Start the stockMonitor
    stockMonitor.Notify()

    // Change the price of the stockMonitor
    stockMonitor.SetPrice(500)

    // Detach an Observer from the stockMonitor
    stockMonitor.Detach(observerA)

    // Change the price of the stockMonitor
    stockMonitor.SetPrice(528)
}
```

In this part

- We create two observers, observerA and observerB.
  Attach them to the stockMonitor.
- Change the price of the stockMonitor.
- We see that observerA and obsererB are both notified.
- Detach observerA from the stockMonitor and change the stock price. We can see that only observerB is notified.

Comment: Where is the implementation of the Update function on the StockObserver type? Currently no actual Update() function is called on the observer instances.