# The Go way to implement the Observer design pattern

Tags: go, design-patterns, observer-pattern

My experience is with OOP languages but I've started trying out Go. I'm having trouble working out the best way to implement the [Observer design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) in Go.

I've organised my project as follows where everything in the `observers` folder is part of `package observers` and everything in the `subjects` folder is part of `package subjects`. The attaching of observers to subjects is done in `main.go`.

```
my-project/
  main.go
  observers/
    observer.go
    observer_one.go
    observer_two.go
  subjects/
    subject.go
    subject_one.go
```

I've seen [this section in the Go wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#interfaces) about interfaces:

> Go interfaces generally belong in the package that uses values of the interface type, not the package that implements those values. The implementing package should return concrete (usually pointer or struct) types: that way, new methods can be added to implementations without requiring extensive refactoring.

Keeping the comment from the Go Wiki in mind. I've implemented like this (left out function implementations):

subject.go:

```golang
type ObserverInterface interface {
    Update(subject *Subject, updateType string)
}

type Subject struct {
    observers map[string][]ObserverInterface
}

func (s *Subject) Attach(observer ObserverInterface, updateType string) {}

func (s *Subject) Detach(observer ObserverInterface, updateType string) {}

func (s *Subject) notify(updateType string) {}
```

observer.go:

```golang
type SubjectInterface interface {
   Attach(observer Observer, updateType string)
   Detach(observer Observer, updateType string)
   notify(updateType string)
}

type Observer struct {
    uuid uuid.UUID
}
```

observer_one.go

```golang
type ObserverOne struct {
    Observer
}

func (o *ObserverOne) Update(subject *SubjectInterface, updateType string) {}
```

main.go

```golang
subjectOne := &SubjectOne{}
observerOne := &ObserverOne{Observer{uuid: uuid.New()}}
subjectOne.Attach(observerOne, "update_type")
```

I expect to be able to use `SubjectInterface` for the argument to the `Update()` method in `ObserverOne` so that I can avoid having dependencies between my `subject` package and my `observer` package but I get the following compile-time error.

```sh
observers/observer_one.go:29:35: cannot use &observer (type *ObserverOne) as type subjects.ObserverInterface in argument to SubjectOne.Subject.Attach:
    *ObserverOne does not implement subjects.ObserverInterface (wrong type for Update method)
        have Update(*SubjectInterface, string)
        want Update(*subjects.Subject, string)
```

If I replace the definition of `Update()` in observer_one.go with the following it compiles fine but i thought the idea was to decouple the packages using interfaces:

```golang
func (o *ObserverOne) Update(subject *subjects.Subject, updateType string) {}
```

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69851172/10153574

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, don't use pointers to interfaces.

```
func (o *ObserverOne) Update(subject *SubjectInterface, updateType string) {}
```

should be

```
func (o *ObserverOne) Update(subject SubjectInterface, updateType string) {}
```

Second, you've defined your interface to require a concrete type:

```
type ObserverInterface interface {
    Update(subject *Subject, updateType string)
}
```

Instead, make it accept an interface:

```
type ObserverInterface interface {
    Update(subject SubjectInterface, updateType string)
}
```

Comment: For your last point, currently `SubjectInterface` is defined in `observer.go` in my `observers` package, so there is a couple ways I could make `Update` in `ObserverInterface` accept the interface.1. define `SubjectInterface` in my `subjects` package as well as in my `observers` package, 2. use `observers.SubjectInterface` or 3. define it in the `subjects` package instead and use `subjects.SubjectInterface` as needed in my `observers` package. 1. doesn't seem right because the same thing is defined in two places and 1. and 3. seem to be going against the recommended way of doing things in Go.

Comment: @thoward: You should define your interfaces in a package independent from your observers and subjects.